# pip doesn't work in Eclipse on Windows 8 (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-8, pip

When I try to type "pip install " or "easy_install ", Python can't recognize the commands (I get a name error).  My system's Path variable is "C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34".  I've tried to use pip through the Python command line as well as Eclipse with the PyDev module.  I know pip is supposed to come installed with Python 3.4.  What's going wrong?

Comment: have you actually tried it via the **Windows** command line?

Comment: @MattDMo How do I do that?

Comment: @MattDMo How do I do that?  I tried "python pip <something>", it says "can't open file: no such file or directory"

Comment: see my answer below...

Comment: open command prompt and type 'pip' and press enter. It'll give you a list of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `pip` under Windows, you need to use the Windows command line program `cmd.exe`. Open the Run dialog with <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, then type ***`cmd`*** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The command line will open up, and you should be able to type, for example, ***`pip install requests`*** to install the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.